# Why \eqref{ } refers to the chapter instead of the equation in this case?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, labels, lncs

I'm writing on Overleaf with the Springer LNCS template, and I labeled an equation as Eq.9:

```
\[
\begin{equation} \label{Eq.9}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{X}_{m \times 1} \\ Y_{1 \times 1}
\end{bmatrix}
| \mathbf{Z, \: W}
\sim \mathrm{N}(\mathbf{W^T Z}, \begin{bmatrix}
\sigma^2_x \mathbf{I}_{m \times m} & \: \\
\: & \sigma^2_y \\
\end{bmatrix})
\end{equation}
\]
```

However, when I tried to refer to it in a sentence later like "compute the score by Eq.9 and Eq.10", only Eq.10 displayed properly as (10) in the pdf output, and where was supposed to display (9) weirdly referred to the chapter instead. What goes wrong? How can I fix it?

```
\item Compute $\mathcal{L}_{co}(\mathbf{X}, Y)$ by \eqref{Eq.9} and \eqref{Eq.10} \\
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Putting `\[` **and**
`\begin{equation}` is a bit too much. Use only `\begin{equation} \label{Eq.9}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{X}_{m \times 1} \\ Y_{1 \times 1}
\end{bmatrix}
| \mathbf{Z, \: W}
\sim \mathrm{N}(\mathbf{W^T Z}, \begin{bmatrix}
\sigma^2_x \mathbf{I}_{m \times m} & \: \\
\: & \sigma^2_y \\
\end{bmatrix})
\end{equation}` (modulo minor improvements).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat You're right! Problem solved! I didn't even notice I put `\[ \]` around it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it s solved by Schrödinger's cat  comment.